# What is the last stage of (human) pregnancy called?

Tags: single-word-requests

If somebody can name the final period/division/stage/state of (human)gestation, I'll be then thankful for that.

I am not looking necessarily for naming a 3-months period time (which also would be okay), but for the last state or condition, when obviously she is about to conceive.

- Swollen womb.
- Size breast increased.
- et cetera.

Comment: I do wish close-voters would indicate how you are supposed to look up a word you don't know.

Comment: @AndrewLeach [Wikipedia: Pregnancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pregnancy#Chronology), [Google: stages of pregnancy](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=stages+of+pregnancy), etc.

Comment: I suggest asking here https://parenting.stackexchange.com/ - Use the tag "pregnancy.

Comment: I don't think you mean 'about to conceive'!

Comment: @KateBunting I guess... I wonder if any other language has a specific word for that.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I'll accept that as an answer because I knew *about to conceive* already, and also because this is the first given definition by google dictionary.

Comment: Googling "stages of pregnancy" leads to 'trimester' (but no other even remotely suitable terms) in the first hit I get. Accepting this as an answer is not appropriate on a site aimed at linguists, I'm afraid. Reasonable research is expected to be shown. Of course, if you think there may be a more precise term for the last couple of weeks say, explain why 'trimester' is inadequate, and you have a valid question.

Comment: I meant that _conception_ is the beginning of the pregnancy, not the end of it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just say *she is **due** any minute* to mean [expected to give birth](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/due) very soon.

Of course, due (to do what?) is a euphemism for **due to give birth**, as pregnancy is both an exciting topic and and personal one worthy of respect and not saying too much. Touching a woman's big belly without even asking was once considered socially acceptable in the US — at the same time when people did not say "pregnant" on the radio. In a family way, maybe, but pregnant, no.

Note that "about to conceive" is what happens at the beginning of the nine months, not the delivery time.

Answer (score 3):

Pregnancy is divided into [trimesters](https://www.lexico.com/definition/trimester):

> A period of three months, especially as a division of the duration of pregnancy.
>
> – Lexico

The different stages are simply the first, second and third trimesters.

Comment: Thanks I've also read wikipedia. Is there a word (verb, noum, et cetera) that defines the state of about giving a birth? I mean we are humans we love to name things. First, second and third phase... It must be a word for that.

Comment: @SNR If you've read Wikipedia then **that research should go in your question.** Your question should also be explicit about what you want to name: the third three-month period, or the act of [parturition](https://www.lexico.com/definition/parturition)?

Comment: I suspect something in between is aimed at, @AndrewLeach: the final portion only of the third trimester. I know of no formal term; but a person I know and love, who has been both a maternity nurse and a grad student in English, favors the expression "ready to pop"; others commonly say *"very* pregnant" (risking reproof from grammar Nazis who try to insist that the adjective *pregnant* admits of no degrees).

Comment: @BrianDonovan One can certainly be *heavily* pregnant. While I haven't tried a pregnancy "reality bib" myself, I'm told that a baby is quite a weight to lug about.

Comment: Heavily pregnant sounds better to me than *very pregnant*.